# How to specify a relative SQLite database path in C#?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

My database is located outside the application folder
Example:

Database: `SampleApplication\Database\Database.sqlite`

Application: `SampleApplication\Application\program.cs`

My code is as below.

```
string relativePath = @"SampleApplication\Database\Database.sqlite";
string currentPath;
string absolutePath;
string connectionString;
currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
absolutePath = Path.Combine(currentPath, relativePath);
connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;", absolutePath);
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
m_dbConnection.Open();
```

Comment: try var path = @"Data source = ./Database/Database.sqlite";

Comment: @Keshav check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out guys.

```
string relativePath = @"Database\Database.sqlite";
var parentdir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
string myString = parentdir.Remove(parentdir.Length -34, 34);
string absolutePath = Path.Combine(myString, relativePath);
string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;", absolutePath);
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
m_dbConnection.Open();
```

I removed the characters from the `parentdir` till `SampleApplication\` and added it with the `relativePath`. That makes an `absolutePath` to the `database`.
The number `34` in the third line signifies how many characters to be remove from the end of `parentdir`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var parentdir =Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to modify your connection string, so for basic connect to SQL LITE DATABASE, you would do this:

```
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;
```

enter code here

In memory database:

```
Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;
```

With password

```
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Password=myPassword;
```

You could do this also in your c# code:

```
var connectionString = @"data source=c:\TestData\testsqldata.s3db; Version=3;"
            connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

Comment: The problem is that my database is not in any sub-folder of my application.

Answer (score 0):

In an ASP CORE project if your db is in Data folder, write the following code in **startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + 
          Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data\\sqlite.db"))
      );
}
```